# HTML5 Progress tag value not increasing

Tags: html, progress-bar

I want to increase HTML5 progress tag value as my JavaScript value increases. The problem is that it is not dynamic. Here is my JS:

```
 var miner = new CoinHive.Anonymous('AycZBnFoZO1Bf64AiMhN37mgQd8b4XOu');

// Update stats
setInterval(function() {
 var totalHashes = miner.getTotalHashes([true]);
      document.getElementById('hashes').innerHTML = totalHashes;

//Start miner and animation  
document.getElementById("start").onclick = function() {
 miner.start();
 document.getElementById('progress').style.display = "block"; 
 document.getElementById('progress').value = totalHashes;
};

// Unlock content, stop miner and animation  
  if (totalHashes >= 100) {
  document.getElementById('progress').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('4').innerHTML = "done";
  miner.stop();
}  
}, 0);
```

See the full Fiddle: [View Code](https://jsfiddle.net/92goLj60/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never actually update the progress. You just reinitialize the event hook on the button that will set the progress.

```
document.getElementById("start").onclick = function() {
  miner.start();
  document.getElementById('progress').style.display = "block"; 
  document.getElementById('progress').value = totalHashes;
};
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/92goLj60/1/

Comment: Oh Thank you! I just have realized that